# SQL - Selecting employees that have ended most recent contract but have other contracts open

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been going around in circles trying to figure this one out.

I'm trying to select employees who have ended their most recent contract but have an active contract still open from previous.

For example, an employee has several contracts (some may be temporary or part time - this is irrelevant) but ends their most recent contract, however, they still continue to be in their older contracts.

Please see the table below as to what I'm trying to achieve - with relevant fields:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| ID   | CONTRACT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4321 | 974         | 321         | 21/01/2004 | 31/12/2016 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4322 | 1485        | 321         | 09/01/2009 | 31/08/2014 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4323 | NULL        | 321         | 25/07/2009 | 31/01/2010 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4324 | 2440        | 321         | 01/06/2012 | NULL       |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4325 | 7368        | 321         | 01/01/2017 | NULL       |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4326 | 7612        | 321         | 14/02/2017 | 06/06/2017 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Here is the code I currently have, which is not bringing back the correct data:

```
select
cond.EMPLOYEE_ID
,cond.END_DATE

from
contracts as cond

join
(select

EMPLOYEE_ID
,START_DATE
,END_DATE

from
contracts

where
END_DATE is null) a on a.EMPLOYEE_ID = cond.employee_id and a.START_DATE <     
cond.END_DATE

group by cond.end_date, cond.EMPLOYEE_ID

having
max(cond.START_DATE) is not null AND cond.END_DATE is not null
```

This is what the code results in (example):

```
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| ID   | CONTRACT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1234 | NULL        | 123         | 03/12/2014 | 26/10/2015 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1235 | NULL        | 123         | 30/10/2015 | 28/01/2016 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1236 | NULL        | 123         | 06/11/2015 | 28/01/2016 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1237 | 1234        | 123         | 07/03/2016 | NULL       |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1238 | NULL        | 123         | 04/04/2017 | 13/04/2017 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1239 | NULL        | 123         | 18/04/2017 | NULL       |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

As you can see, the most recent contract does not have an end date but there is an open contract.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this to the post. SQL Server 2012

Comment: can you post the expected result as well?

Comment: Please see the first table for expected result.

Comment: what is the input that produces this result?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to achieve, hence my question.

Comment: ok can we see an extract of the table as it is currently please? - we need to understand how your data is stored

Comment: I think you need to clarify. Why is there a contract-id of null in your shown results? etc. maybe you can provide simplified example data and what result you want to select of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the most recent `start_date`, `end_date`, and the count of `open_contracts` using a windowed aggregate function `count()` [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) :

```
select 
    c.id
  , c.contract_id
  , c.employee_id
  , start_date    
  , end_date      
  , max_start_date = x.start_date
  , max_end_date   = x.end_date
  , x.open_contracts
from contracts c
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.start_date
      , i.end_date
      , open_contracts = count(case when i.end_date is null then 1 end) over(partition by i.employee_id)
    from contracts i
    where i.employee_id = c.employee_id
    order by i.start_date desc
    ) x
where x.end_date is not null
  and x.open_contracts > 0
order by c.employee_id, c.start_date asc
```

---

test setup with some additional cases:

```
create table contracts (id int, contract_id int, employee_id int, start_date date, end_date date);
insert into contracts values
 (4321, 974, 321, '20040121', '20161231')
,(4322, 1485, 321, '20090109', '20140831')
,(4323, null, 321, '20090725', '20100131')
,(4324, 2440, 321, '20120601', null)
,(4325, 7368, 321, '20170101', null)
,(4326, 7612, 321, '20170214', '20170606')
,(1, 1, 1, '20160101', null)
,(2, 2, 1, '20160701', '20161231')
,(3, 3, 1, '20170101', null)        /* most recent is open, do not return */
,(4, 4, 2, '20160101', '20170630')
,(5, 5, 2, '20160701', '20161231')
,(6, 6, 2, '20170101', '20170630')  /* most recent is closed, no others open, do not return */
,(7, 7, 3, '20160101', '20170630')
,(8, 8, 3, '20160701', null)
,(9, 9, 3, '20170101', '20170630')  /* most recent is closed, one other open, return */
;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BUYKJ77928

returns:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
|  id  | contract_id | employee_id | start_date |  end_date  | max_start_date | max_end_date | open_contracts |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
|    7 | 7           |           3 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 | 2017-01-01     | 2017-06-30   |              1 |
|    8 | 8           |           3 | 2016-07-01 | NULL       | 2017-01-01     | 2017-06-30   |              1 |
|    9 | 9           |           3 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-06-30 | 2017-01-01     | 2017-06-30   |              1 |
| 4321 | 974         |         321 | 2004-01-21 | 2016-12-31 | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
| 4322 | 1485        |         321 | 2009-01-09 | 2014-08-31 | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
| 4323 | NULL        |         321 | 2009-07-25 | 2010-01-31 | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
| 4324 | 2440        |         321 | 2012-06-01 | NULL       | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
| 4325 | 7368        |         321 | 2017-01-01 | NULL       | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
| 4326 | 7612        |         321 | 2017-02-14 | 2017-06-06 | 2017-02-14     | 2017-06-06   |              2 |
+------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: This is the best solution which picks up everything. A couple of the other solutions provided didn't take into account multiple contracts starting on the same date (which happens quite a lot here). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a SQL-server expert, but you might try something similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   contracts cont
WHERE  cont.end_date IS NOT NULL
  AND  cont.end_date <= SYSDATE
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   contracts recent
                   WHERE  recent.employee_id = cont.employee_id
                     AND  recent.start_date > cont.start_date)
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   contracts openc
               WHERE  openc.employee_id = cont.employee_id
                 AND  (openc.end_date IS NULL OR openc.end_date > SYSDATE))
```

The first 2 conditions search for closed contracts.
The next one ("NOT EXISTS") makes sure the selected contract is the most recent one.
The last part assures there are other open contracts.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, it doesn't seem to pull back as many results (which are correct) from other solutions posted. I think it's something to do with multiple contracts starting on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude.

```
SELECT [EMPLOYEE_ID]

FROM [contracts]

WHERE [END_DATE] IS NULL

AND [EMPLOYEE_ID] IN (SELECT B.[EMPLOYEE_ID] FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by [EMPLOYEE_ID] ORDER BY[START_DATE] DESC)
, [EMPLOYEE_ID]
, [CONTRACT_ID]
, [END_DATE]

FROM [contracts]

) A
WHERE A.[END_DATE] IS NOT NULL
AND A.[RowN] = 1) B)
```

Comment: *Update* I added in distinct due to duplication.

Comment: *Update 2* This seems to miss employees who have multiple contracts which start on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `CTE`

See it in action: http://rextester.com/HQVXF56741

In the code below, I changed the dateformat which you may not have to do.

```
set dateformat dmy
declare @table table (ID int,CONTRACT_ID int, EMPLOYEE_ID int, [START_DATE] datetime,   END_DATE datetime)
insert into @table
values
(4321,974,321,'21/01/2004','31/12/2016'),
(4322,1485,321,'09/01/2009','31/08/2014'),
(4323,NULL,321,'25/07/2009','31/01/2010'),
(4324,2440,321,'01/06/2012',NULL),
(4325,7368,321,'01/01/2017',NULL),
(4326,7612,321,'14/02/2017','06/06/2017')

--this applies a row_number to each contract per employee
--the most recent contract (by start date) gets a 1
;with cte as(
    select
        EMPLOYEE_ID
        ,ID
        ,row_number() over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID order by [START_DATE] desc) as ContractRecentcy
    from @table)


--this will return all contacts that are open, which aren't the most recent for the employee.
select
    t.*
from 
    @table t
where
    t.END_DATE is null
    and t.ID not in (select ID from cte where ContractRecentcy = 1)

set dateformat mdy
```